# Error during negotiate request, ERR_CACHE_MISS

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, signalr

Connection failure while connecting to signalr hub without generated proxy from Cordova on Android

> jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js 
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS on negotiate file

.NET client works fine

Manual negotiate request on Chrome on desktop and android returns ConnectionId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved, I do not know how though.
I'll post, if this repeats. Let me know, if you face it and know how to resolve.